# Prototype code not working when jQuyery library is loaded on top

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, coexistence

My **prototype** code no longer works when I load in the **jquery** library, even though jquery is the first library to be loaded.

The html of the page looks a bit like so:

```
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/effects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/prototip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dragdrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/default.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/limitfocus.js"></script>
...
</head>

<body>

<input type="radio" name="useOtherAddress" id="useOtherAddress_y" value="y" onclick="selectAddress()">
<input type="radio" name="useOtherAddress" id="useOtherAddress_n" value="y" onclick="selectAddress()">

<div id="myAddress" style="display: none;">
...
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // the piece of protptype code no longer working 
  function selectAddress () {
    var t = $('myAddress');
    if ($('useOtherAddress_n').checked) {
      Effect.Appear(t);
      return;
    }
    t.hide();
  }
</script>
```

Anybody have any ideas? This page:

http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

suggests that loading jquery first should make everything **handy-dandy**. But it's not :[

Comment: Define "no longer works". What happens? What errors do you get?

Comment: With firebug on, i can't see any errors. Clicking on radio buttons doesn't show / hide the div as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), like this:

```
jQuery.noConflict(); //or possibly $j = jQuery.noConflict();
function selectAddress () {
```

Then load jQuery *last* (but before it's plugins) so that the [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) will restore the `$` to its previous value (Prototype).

Comment: I think the OP know's that and he means [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries#Including_jQuery_before_Other_Libraries) - where it says `There is no need for overriding the $-function by calling "jQuery.noConflict()".` - I myself is confused with the docs too.

Comment: @Reigel -That only holds true if the library you're including afterwards doesn't do an `if(typeof $ == "undefined")` type check, that documentation is shaky at best, it's an assumption, and not always a correct one.

Comment: @Nick Will try that out and see how I go

Answer (score 2):

If you can help it at all - the code you show doesn't display any compelling need to use both libraries at once - as a general policy, using jQuery and Prototype alongside should be the last resort or a temporary workaround, for example while switching frameworks.

Even if you get the frameworks running together, there are dozens of subtle pitfalls in DOM handling and such that may bite you in the arse later, creating untraceable bugs.

It's really, really best to use one JS framework only.

Comment: `It's really, really best to use one JS framework only.` +1 for this.

Comment: that's because I haven't added the jquery code in yet :) I'm just loading in the jquery library at this stage.

Comment: & @Reigel. I do understand that is the ideal. But I have a substantial chunk of jquery code that needs to be run on one single page in a framework that utilises the prototype library

Comment: @superspace that may work okay. I'm strongly against habitually using both frameworks together, but as long as  Protoype and jQUery don't manipulate the same DOM elements or stuff like that, chances are everything works out well.

Answer (score 1):

+1 as a general policy, using jQuery and Prototype alongside should be the last resort or a temporary workaround, for example while switching frameworks.

My guess is that you are using jQuery with the $ variable or using a function that will cause conflicting!

when ever you want to use jQuery use `jQuery` instead of `$` like `jQuery(#id).click();`.
in jQuery  `$` is just an alias for `jQuery`, so all functionality is available without using  `$`. If we need to use prtotype alongside with `jQuery`, you can return control of  `$` back to `prototype` with a call to `$.noConflict()`
if you wanna use $ for both you can do that. here's how:

...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/effects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/prototip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dragdrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/default.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/limitfocus.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
...
</head>

<body>

<input type="radio" name="useOtherAddress" id="useOtherAddress_y" value="y" onclick="selectAddress()">
<input type="radio" name="useOtherAddress" id="useOtherAddress_n" value="y" onclick="selectAddress()">

<div id="myAddress" style="display: none;">
...
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // the piece of protptype code no longer working 
$.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //jquery with $

  });
//prototype with $
  function selectAddress () {
    var t = $('myAddress');
    if ($('useOtherAddress_n').checked) {
      Effect.Appear(t);
      return;
    }
    t.hide();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Also if you can tell me what error you are getting, I think it will really help!

Comment: With my current setup, with firebug turned on, and clicking on the radio buttons, i get zilch. Nothing. No errors. It just doesn't work.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It is also correct and it's an extension of the answer by Nick. Answer has been marked as useful